# Import many file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to import a file in my angular application, when i click the button for the first time to import a file, the import is successfully done, but the second time it fails

```
<input type="file" name="file" (change)="fileChange()" #fileInput style="display: none" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fileInput.click()">EXCEL</button>

export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild("fileInput", { static: true }) fileInput;

  public fileChange() {
    if (this.fileInput.nativeElement.files.length > 0) {
      this.generateDocument(this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0]);
    }
  }

  public generateDocument(file: File) {
    this.readExcel(file).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  public readExcel(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let workbook;
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.onload = function() {
        let data = reader.result;
        workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: "binary",
          cellDates: true,
          cellNF: false,
          cellText: false
        });
        resolve(
          XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]])
        );
      };
    });
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cikjw)

Comment: I think that's because of `change` event. If you re-upload same file it won't invoke `change` function, Try uploading different files, to solve this you have to clear input file value after your necessary work is done.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value bind with your file input won't change if it's the same file. Hence the `(change)` event fails to trigger. This is a normal scenario and no one will repeatedly upload the same file. If you still want to do that, try this :

- Bind the file input to a variable and set it value to null or an empty string.
- After reading the file completely, reset the value.

**app.component.ts** :

```
fileInputModel : any = '';

public generateDocument(file: File) {
    this.readExcel(file).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.fileInputModel = '';
    });
}
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<input 
  type="file" 
  name="file" 
  (change)="fileChange()" 
  #fileInput 
  [(ngModel)]="fileInputModel"
  style="display: none" />
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2szrtu

Another workaround : Use an **NgForm** to wrap the input and `reset()` it after upload.